# 302 redirect loop error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having issues with a redirect. I'm Not sure if i'm doing this right but I created a landing page in Wordpress and saved it in a directory on the sever named landing. I don't want to hurt my SEO so I want to do a temp redirect. I added this code to the .htaccess file `Redirect 302 / http://casinofandango.com/landing/index.php/` But I get a redirect loop. Whats really strange is when I remove the code from the .htaccess and re-upload it and refresh the page it takes me to the landing like it should. If I reload it again it takes me back to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RedirectMatch` instead. The `Redirect` directive links the paths together, so when you redirect `/` to something, it's not only "/", but "/" followed *by anything*.

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(?:index\.php)/?$ http://casinofandango.com/landing/index.php/
```